# use Chef insert_line_if_no_match with "\:"

Tags: regex, ruby, chef-infra

How do I have to change my regex so that the line is not rewritten into the file every time when the code is called?

```
line_text = 'Everything is ok\:ok check /test/user/*'
ruby_block "update file" do
  block do
    fe = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/home/user/test")
    fe.insert_line_if_no_match(/#{line_text}/, line_text)
    fe.write_file
  end
end
```

I think the "\:" is the problem that the line is rewritten every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash character is "special" in a regular expression in that it escapes the following character so that this next character is to be considered a normal character. The asterisk at the end is also special in that it denotes the previous character to occur 0 or more times.

You are building your regex there without handling these cases. Following this, the backslash character in your original string gets ignored by the regex match and the asterisk character might result in a slightly incorrect match (again without considering a literal asterisk in the source string).

To fix this, you can escape the `line_text` variable when building your regex by using [`Regexp.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

```
line_text = 'Everything is ok\:ok check /test/user/*'
ruby_block "update file" do
  block do
    fe = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/home/user/test")
    fe.insert_line_if_no_match(/#{Regexp.escape(line_text)}/, line_text)
    fe.write_file
  end
end
```